Would a stealth car be street legal?
Say, for purposes of conjecture, that a certain carmaker decides to build a "stealth car." It is effectively invisible to police traffic radar.
Would such a car be street legal? It is explicitly designed to make it harder for police to detect (let alone prove) traffic violations by the vehicle's driver.
Note: while I have framed the question under Texas' jurisdiction, I am also interested in other jurisdictions as well.

In UK they also use average speed checks by number plate recognition (without radar), so "radar-proof" would be useless. A blackbird-like shape isn't illegal as it is not a radar 'jammer'. An electronic device that jams radar is illegal, but they are rare. More usual would be a radar detection device that warns the driver.

@WeatherVane - And in at least one US state (Virginia), radar detectors are illegal.

@WPNSGuy I meant to say they are illegal in UK too.

FWIW, lots of things that make it harder for the police to do their job (like a VPN, burner phone, or even a fake moustache) aren't illegal.

Sometime in the last century, Car and Driver magazine constructed such a vehicle by covering all possible surfaces with radio wave absorbing material. What little I can remember from decades ago was that it was undetectable to police speed radar up to about 30 meters, at which point any sane driver would have slowed to legal speed.

Would the downvoter please explain his is her reasoning?

Existing laws on laser and radar jammers would quite possibly apply. They are summarized at https://www.automoblog.com/are-radar-detectors-legal/

The law does not say "You aren't allowed to go faster than the limit, unless you can't be clocked". So even if this car is legal and passes all the requirements (e.g. unobstructed visibility for the driver, correct type of lights, etc), that would not make it legal to race with such a car on public roads.

@PMF I am not questioning whether it's illegal to exceed the speed limit. My question is whether it is legal to drive a car explicitly designed to foil methods for detection such violations.

germany
There has not been a case yet, since that technology does not exist, but I would assume that it falls under §23 StVO, just like laser and radar detectors and jammers:

(1c) Wer ein Fahrzeug führt, darf ein technisches Gerät nicht betreiben oder betriebsbereit mitführen, das dafür bestimmt ist, Verkehrsüberwachungsmaßnahmen anzuzeigen oder zu stören. Das gilt insbesondere für Geräte zur Störung oder Anzeige von Geschwindigkeitsmessungen (Radarwarn- oder Laserstörgeräte). Bei anderen technischen Geräten, die neben anderen Nutzungszwecken auch zur Anzeige oder Störung von Verkehrsüberwachungsmaßnahmen verwendet werden können, dürfen die entsprechenden Gerätefunktionen nicht verwendet werden.

Translated:

(1c) Anyone driving a vehicle may not operate or carry a technical device that is intended to display or interfere with traffic monitoring measures. This applies in particular to devices for disrupting or displaying speed measurements (radar warning or laser jamming devices). The corresponding device functions may not be used with other technical devices which, in addition to other purposes, can also be used to display or disrupt traffic monitoring measures.


Stealth is mostly achieved through passive design features like choice of materials or the shape of the vehicle body. Would that really count as "operating/carrying a technical device intended to interfere with traffic monitoring measures"? There may be no particular "technical device" other than the car itself.

As I said, I cannot speculate about future tech built into a future vehicle as judged by a future judge in a fictional future case. What I posted certainly is the legal gounds that it will be decided on. My guess it that "technical device" will apply to a specific paint job with radar absorbing paint for example. It already applies to having reflective surfaces specifically to disturb lasers. It doesn't have to be electronic, to be a "technical device".


"Stealth" is not invisibility. Current stealth aircraft (F-22/F-35) make it harder to find, but not impossible. At the distances of traffic radar, it would be detected.

In military aircraft, stealth and detection is a moving target. You build a stealth aircraft, your opponent builds better radar. Back and forth.

Visible light vs radar. Your car is on the road, it will be seen. Exceeding the posted speed limit does not really need an exact number determined by radar. In a chase, all the cop really needs is his documented speed as he is chasing you. "I'm going 110mph, and he's pulling away from me."

Cost and potential customer base.

Currently, there is no law against a stealth car, because they do not yet exist.



Note that radar jammers are illegal in all states. But this is worse than a stealth car, because it prevents getting the speed of all the cars in the area, not just one invisible car.

Reinforcing point #3:  (1) any visible car would also be susceptible to speed enforcement by aircraft.  (2)  Most police "radar" is actually LIDAR, using beams of infrared light, and license plates are specifically designed to be highly reflective in the visible and infrared.  So even if the body of the car was "stealthy" you couldn't eliminate the return from the license plate.

@MichaelSeifert Most police radar is radar. LIDAR requires significantly more effort to use as the narrow beamwidth requires the user point it using a sight at individual vehicles. The officer must then be stopped or work with a second, stationary person. LIDAR is also not subject to FCC rules, thus in most places is legal to jam.

It seems like basically this entire answer is useless. As I read it, OP doesn't care whether this car could actually exist; it's just a hypothetical drawn up to illustrate a legal issue. And the single sentence that addresses the legal issue is pretty faulty.

@user71659 Hmm, interesting.  Perhaps the impression I got from Wikipedia about "most police radar" is an overstatement.  But I still suspect that "stealth cars" would be fairly susceptible to LIDAR systems if the police were using them.

@MichaelSeifert It's much easier to make a stealth LIDAR car, paint it with a layer of organic dye that absorbs 904 nm. Think laser safety glasses. The far longer microwave wavelength means the equivalent is several inches of absorptive foam.
